# Retrofit requests are not visible in Fiddler

Tags: android, retrofit, fiddler

I've set up my Android emulator and Fiddler2 by this [manual](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid). I can monitor requests from a mobile browser correctly. But when my app makes requests to the remote server via Retrofit library, these requests are not shown in fiddler. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of references out there.  These were the one's I came accross with most complete answer (covered both http and https).

This [document](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp) shows how to set the proxy in your android app to use Fiddler.  The proxy should only be used when triaging:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

If your are using 'HTTPS', you may also need to configure a keystore.  See [this](http://codeketchup.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-use-eclipse-with-fiddler-step-by.html) blog.  Basics are:

1. Export your Fiddler Certificate
2. Create a Keystore
3. Configure System with Keystore (from blog, below):

   `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\security\\FiddlerKeystore");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "my#password");`